# Add class through knockout if viewmodel property is not null

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model property like so

```
var customProperties = JSON.parse(this.model.get('CustomProperties'));
viewModel.clickEventAction = customProperties.clickEventAction; //returns a string such as "here" or "there"
```

and I am trying to see if this exists in the html and if it is then assign a class to the element. I have a click that I would only like to happen if this is not null to cut down on click events that are called.

I have tried several different ways but nothing seems to work. Like...

```
data-bind="class: {thisisclass: clickEventAction()}

data-bind="class: {thisisclass: clickEventAction}

data-bind="attr: {class: clickEventAction()}

data-bind="css: {thisisclass: clickEventAction() < 0}
```

and I've tried several other ways, but nothing seems to want to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the property is not observable it is not a function.  You can evaluate it directly without "()".

```
data-bind="css: clickEventAction == null ? 'class-name' : '';"
```

Where "class-name" is the class you want to assign to the DOM object.